# IWYU failing/unclear output?

Tags: c++, include-what-you-use

I recently installed `include-what-you-use` (IWYU) to try it out. I am on version include-what-you-use 0.12 based on clang version 9.0.1-10. (My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL1)

I tried to do a very simple example on a source code file, but it quickly comes back as an error on the very first include? (Which is just a c standard library file)

After running

`include-what-you-use myutils.cpp`:

```
In file included from myutils.cpp:8:
In file included from ./myutils.h:11:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/cfloat:42:10: fatal error: 'float.h' file not found
#include <float.h>
^~~~~~~~~
```

Why is it error'ing out on a c standard library include?

I cannot post the entire source here, and without extensive testing I am not sure what minimal example would cause this problem.

Am I just mis-using IWYU? I installed it via `apt` rather than building it and llvm/clang/etc from scratch. Is that fine?

Comment: Have you already set the path correcctly and updated the required environment variables?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa No, I did not. What changes need to be made? (The installation instructions are a little unclear. There's no section for package manager users, and most of the path changes seem to be related to those using cmake, which I'm not trying to do)